# Wrong output due to shl on al and ax in the code NASM 64 bit programming

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-64

I writing a code to multiply two 8-bit hexadecimal number and applying the shift and add method. I have taken the two inputs in the variable named "a" and "b" which are of byte type and storing them in al and bl.

During multiplication the al is shifted left and bl is shifted right.
Later, in the loop, I am adding ax(a) with dx register(initialised with 0).
But, the problem is that when shl ax,1 
is replaced with 
shl al,1 then I am not getting the required output. ie - a=12 and b=10 then only 20 is getting printed and not 120.

Do explain, why can't I write shl al,1.

Here is the code

```
%macro print 2
    mov rax,1
    mov rdi,1
    mov rsi,%1
    mov rdx,%2
    syscall
%endmacro

%macro accept 2
    mov rax,0
    mov rdi,0
    mov rsi,%1
    mov rdx,%2
    syscall
%endmacro

%macro exit 0
    mov rax,60
    mov rdi,0
    syscall
%endmacro

section .data
    a db 12H
    b db 10H
    msg db 10,"Result : ",10
    len equ $-msg
;------------------------
section .bss
    tempbuff resb 16    ;temporary buffer for displaying the ascii

;------------------------

section .text
global _start
_start:
    mov rdx,0
    mov al,byte[a]  ;al is multiplicand
    mov bl,byte[b]  ;bl is multiplier
    mov rcx,8
    lp:
        shr bl,1    
        jnc haha
        add dx,ax
        haha:
            shl ax,1    ;shl al,1 doesn;t work
    loop lp
    mov rbx,0
    mov rbx,rdx
    call hex_ascii      ;converting the hex no into ascii

exit

hex_ascii:
    mov rsi,tempbuff
    mov rcx,16
    mov rax,0
    bah:
        rol rbx,4
        mov al,bl
        and al,0FH
        cmp al,09H
        jbe add30
        add al,07H
        add30:
            add al,30H
        mov [rsi],al
        inc rsi
    loop bah
    print tempbuff,16   
ret
```

Comment: If you have an 8-bit value in `al` and you want to shift it left then add to `dx`, you need to shift `ax` left because otherwise you lose bits off of the multiplicand. In other words, you want to keep shifting it left, *keeping all of the bits*, and adding to the intermediate result every time you see a 1 in the multiplier.

Comment: But when I shift the al bits left then won't the shifted bits got to the ah part of the ax register. How will I then loose them

Comment: `shl al,1` does not affect `ah` at all. It only affects `ah`. That's why you need `shl ax,1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an 8-bit value in `al` and you want to shift it left then add to `dx`, you need to shift `ax` left because otherwise you lose bits off of the multiplicand. In other words, you want to keep shifting it left, *keeping all of the bits*, and adding to the intermediate result every time you see a 1 in the multiplier.

`shl al,1` does not affect `ah` at all. It only affects `ah`. That's why you need `shl ax,1`. Since `shl al,1` shifts

Here's an example. Initially:

```
al = 01011001
ax = 0000000001011001
bl = 00010111
dx = 0000000000000000
```

Shift right `bl` and get a 1 bit, shift `al` left. We have a 1 bit from the `bl` shift, so add `ax` to `dx`:

```
al = 10110010
ax = 0000000010110010
bl = 00001011
dx = 0000000010110010
```

Shift right `bl` and get a 1 bit, shift `al` left. We have a 1 bit from the `bl` shift, so add `ax` to `dx`:

```
al = 01100100
ax = 0000000001100100  <-- wrong! result of shifting al
bl = 00000101
dx = 0000000100010110  <-- wrong because ax was wrong
```

Uh oh, trouble. `ax` is wrong now. We lost the bit shifted left out of `al`.

This is what we want:

```
al = 01100100
ax = 0000000101100100  <-- This is what we want, result of shifting ax
bl = 00000101
dx = 0000001000010110  <-- This is what we want, from correct ax
```

If you look at the [documentation for `shl`](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_285.html) you'll find that the upper bit of `al` is shifted into the CF (carry flag) on a `shl al,1` instruction. You could then rotate that bit into the `ah` if you wish using the "rotate through carry":

```
shl al,1
rcl ah,1
```

But you can get the result you want using the one instruction:

```
shl ax,1
```

Comment: Fun fact: you could also `adc ah,ah` instead of `rcl ah,1`.  The existing bits shift left 1 (because that's what `add same,same` does), then CF is added and becomes the low bit.  In fact, *if restricting yourself only to 8-bit registers*, `add al,al` / `adc ah,ah` would probably be the best implementation for modern CPUs.  (Better throughput than RCL).  But of course `shl ax,1` or better, `add ax,ax`, is by far the best.  Or actually `add eax,eax` for x86-64.  The only difference between `shl` by 1 vs. `add` is how some flags other than CF and ZF are set, and that add runs on more ports.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes, indeed. I was more focused on answering the OP's question as to why a simple `shl al,1` wasn't working but `shl ax,1` was, and I got lazy regarding other possible options. Not sure why the rotate-through-carry popped in my head first.

Comment: `shl` and `rcl` are a better illustration of doing it like the OP (without introducing the concept of adds being equivalent to shifts, or optimizing by doing that like actual compilers https://godbolt.org/g/TbczcT),  My comment wasn't a suggested improvement to your answer, just a fun fact / related reading.